# TranslateAnimated ImageView Flicker

Tags: java, android

I have one big problem. I use this code to animate ImageView to horizontal move one ImageView from current X position to 0.

Here is the animation code

```
    translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, translateX, 0, 0);
    translate.setDuration(400);
    translate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            txtTitle.setText(String.format("Translate: %d %d", translateX, lpView1.leftMargin));
            lpView1.leftMargin = 0;
            mainSwitchBtn.setLayoutParams(lpView1);
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

    });
    translate.reset();
    translate.setFillAfter(false);
    mainSwitchBtn.clearAnimation();
    mainSwitchBtn.startAnimation(translate);
```

When animation is ended, I have moved ImageView to 0. At that I see flicker of ImageView. I do not know what is a problem. Can some one help me?

**EDIT: Founded Problem**

I have founded what is a problem in my code.

I have replaced this code

```
mainSwitchBtn.setLayoutParams(lpView1);
```

With this

```
mainSwitchBtn.layout(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I do not know what is a difference between setting margins in layout params and set params to view object or use .layout function but now I have not flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like animation ends and your imageview returning to original non-animated image, maybe you should try to use HorizontalScrollView instead of animation

Comment: Thanks for try. I have founded solution

Comment: Glad you find it, by the way let me explain how it works, in previous code lpView1.leftMargin = 0;
            mainSwitchBtn.setLayoutParams(lpView1); you set margin to 0 but there maybe some padding left whose value not 0 but in later code you set left position to 0, so it positions to leftmost.